# Flywaydb multiple config files for migration is failing

Tags: flyway

We have tried to migrate some SQL versions in a single database and it went well. When to tried to implement the migrations for multiple databases at the same time by passing multiple config files is failing.

The issue is it takes only the last config file and the migration is performed only for the database mentioned in the last config file, when passed the multiple config files in "`-configFiles`" parameter.

Below is the screenshot of the same, it took only `flywayconfdb.conf` file and left other files.

```
[oracle@localhost flyway-5.1.4]$ ./flyway -configFiles=/home/oracle/flyway/flyway-5.1.4/conf/flyway.conf,/home/oracle/flyway/flyway-5.1.4/conf/flywayjiradb.conf,/home/oracle/flyway/flyway-5.1.4/conf/flywayconfdb.conf info
Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXXXX:1521/confdb (Oracle 12.2)
Schema version: << Empty Schema >>

+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
| Category | Version | Description | Type | Installed On | State |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
| No migrations found                                            |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
```

Please help us in resolving the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flyway merges the config files. It doesn't do a separate migration for each one.

For each config file, Flyway [adds the content to a Properties map](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/f3e7f8f0c603495ae6aa48a1c3d08b84dc734aee/flyway-commandline/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/commandline/Main.java#L405). `Properties` has only one value per key, so if the same key appears in a second config file it would overwrite the previous value. This is why it seems like just the settings from the last config file are used.

It allows you to define some common settings somewhere, for example in `~/flyway.conf`, which could be merged with some more specific settings, e.g. in individual projects.

But it doesn't allow you to migrate multiple databases in a single run. You need to run Flyway once per database:

```
./flyway -configFiles=/home/oracle/flyway/flyway-5.1.4/conf/flywayjiradb.conf info
./flyway -configFiles=/home/oracle/flyway/flyway-5.1.4/conf/flywayconfdb.conf info
```

The documentation describes the [Overriding Order](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#overriding-order) as:

- Command-line arguments
- Environment variables
- Custom config files
- `<current-dir>/flyway.conf`
- `<user-home>/flyway.conf`
- `<install-dir>/conf/flyway.conf`
- Flyway command-line defaults

With settings defined higher up the list having greater precedence.

The documentation gives the following example:

> The means that if for example flyway.url is both present in a config
>   file and passed as -url= from the command-line, the command-line
>   argument will take precedence and be used.

The Custom config files (-configFiles) lines could be expanded as:

- Command-line arguments
- Environment variables
- **Custom config file n**
- ...
- **Custom config file 2**
- **Custom config file 1**
- `<current-dir>/flyway.conf`
- `<user-home>/flyway.conf`
- `<install-dir>/conf/flyway.conf`
- Flyway command-line defaults

And a corresponding example could be:

> The means that if for example flyway.url is both present in **custom config file 1** and **custom config file 2**, the **custom config file 2** settings will take precedence and be used.

Similarly, if the `flyway.url` was also in **custom config file n** that would override that setting from **custom config file 2**.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Below is from flyway documentation. I am trying to understand whether the database names which are mentioned in the multiple config files points to one or multiple databases? 

 To pass in multiple files, separate their names with commas:

> flyway -configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf,other.conf migrate

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/

Comment: Even if `myAlternativeConfig.conf` and `other.conf` did point to different databases, only the `flyway.url` from `other.conf` would be used, as it would override the one in `myAlternativeConfig.conf`. The documentation describes the Overriding Order here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#overriding-order

Comment: Updated my answer with some further details. Does that answer your question? Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense. Thank you so much for the insight.